# check the differentiability of the following function $f(z)=\frac{x^3y^5(x+iy)}{(x^6+y^{10})}$ when $z \neq 0$, $f(z)=0$ when $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Though the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied at the origin, the function is not analytic. how to check the differentiability of this function?

Comment: I cannot prove that the differentiation of the function doesn't exist.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that$$\frac{f(x+yi)-f(0)}{x+yi}=\frac{x^3y^5}{x^6+y^{10}}$$and that therefore$$(\forall t\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}):\frac{f(t^5+t^3i)-f(0)}{t^5+t^3i}=\frac{t^{30}}{2t^{30}}=\frac12\neq0=\lim_{h\to0,\ h\in\mathbb R}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}h.$$

Comment: Got your point. Thank you very much for answering.